# В дизайнере статус юзерконтрола застревает на дефолтном значении enum в DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 2 DependencyProperty вот такого вида (обновлено):

```
public enum ShapeCategories { triangle, circle, rectangle }
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Shape", typeof(ShapeCategories), typeof(StateLampControl), new PropertyMetadata(ShapeCategories.circle, new PropertyChangedCallback(ShapePropertyChanged)));

private static void ShapePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ CallFigure((ShapeCategories)d.GetValue(ShapeProperty)); }

public ShapeCategories Shape
{
    get { return(ShapeCategories)GetValue(ShapeProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ShapeProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Юзерконтрол сделан в виде dll-ки, добавлен в новый проект. Добавляется на форму, оба свойства можно менять через окошко Properties.

(upd)Всё бы было хорошо, но когда задаётся дефолтное значение, Shape="значение" пропадает из xaml и дальнейшее изменение обоих свойств не меняет отображение контрола до rebuild-а.
Если дефолтное значение не указано, нулевые значения enum-а с самого начала не меняют отображение контрола и после нескольких изменений опять же всё застревает.

Если в Shape="значение" руками вписать triangle, всё работает как надо.
Такое поведение наблюдается только в дизайнере, комбобоксы на форме прекрасно меняют и форму, и цвет контрола.

Как сделать так, чтобы в дизайнере не застревало на нулевых и дефолтных значениях?

Comment: Для начала, вы не должны вызывать что-то постороннее, наподобие `CallFigure(value);`, в сеттере. Сеттер очень часто вызывается не напрямую, так что ваш вызов не будет работать.

Comment: А вот вызов через `ShapePropertyChanged` — правильный.

Comment: Да, забыл снести, когда делал коллбэк. Но вот на итоговую ситуацию не влияет никак, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я сам дурак. Лез смотреть каждую ошибку в интернете, и конечно же всё запорол.

Коллбэк должен быть вот таким, иначе он потребует статическое всё, тогда надо будет делать экземпляр класса и присваивать в него this, тогда всё прекращает работать как надо.

```
private static void ShapePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
StateLampControl control = (StateLampControl)d;
control.CallFigure((ShapeCategories)e.NewValue); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Одна из очевидных проблем — несоответствие между именем свойства, как вы его объявляете (`ShapeCatProperty`), и именем, под которым вы регистрируете свойство (`"Shape"`)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapeCatProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Shape",
        typeof(ShapeCategories),
        typeof(StateLampControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(ShapeCategories.triangle,
                             new PropertyChangedCallback(ShapePropertyChanged)));

private static void ShapePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
                                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ CallFigure((ShapeCategories)d.GetValue(ShapeCatProperty)); }

public ShapeCategories Shape
{
    get { return(ShapeCategories)GetValue(ShapeCatProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ShapeCatProperty, value);
        CallFigure(value);
    }
}
```

Ваши объявления должны совпадать:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Shape",
        typeof(ShapeCategories),
        typeof(StateLampControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(ShapeCategories.triangle,
                             new PropertyChangedCallback(ShapePropertyChanged)));
```

Comment: Поменял. Ничего не изменилось. Если сносить свойства вручную, всё в порядке. Если изменять через Properties - застревает на нулевом.

Comment: Застревало на дефолтных всё-таки. Убрал дефолтные в PropertyMetadata. Теперь ещё страннее. А при установке нулевых они вообще не применяются - когда выбраны triangle и stop - отображается синий круг - таким контрол выглядит в дизайнере самого контрола. Изредка после перетыкивания значений, при rebuild-е выдавало property value is not valid